# Cannot print Turkish specific characters in C# console application

Tags: c#, windows, localization

Following source code:

```
Console.WriteLine("01- ııı");
Console.WriteLine("02- İİİ");
Console.WriteLine("03- ööö");
Console.WriteLine("04- ÖÖÖ");
Console.WriteLine("05- üüü");
Console.WriteLine("06- ÜÜÜ");
Console.WriteLine("07- şşş");
Console.WriteLine("08- ŞŞŞ");
Console.WriteLine("09- ğğğ");
Console.WriteLine("10- ĞĞĞ");
```

gives me this output:

```
01- iii
02- III
03- ööö
04- ÖÖÖ
05- üüü
06- ÜÜÜ
07- sss
08- SSS
09- ggg
10- GGG
```

Line 01,02,07,08,09,10 are wrong.

I know all these letters are UNICODE letters. They should be displayed correctly.

```
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.
Current System Locale: English (United States)
Current Location: Turkey
Cuurent Language for non-unicode programs:English (United States)
```

Any solution or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This could be a console issue, or it could be a source/compilation issue. We can't tell just from that - you should print out diagnostics for the Unicode value of each character in your string.

Comment: So how can i print out diagnostics for Unicode value ?

Comment: Just cast the character to `int`.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding.aspx

There are also links on the bottom about Unicode in a Console window.

Comment: @Davio , your answer helped me. Thanks.